'n' vs 's' command for Python debugger (pdb)
I'm new to pdb and trying to learn. There is one thing that's bugging me a lot. Lot of examples that I read on blogs mention a code like this below:
import pdb

def buggy_function(x):
    result = 0
    for i in range(x):
        result += i / (i - 4)
    return result

# Use pdb.run() to debug
pdb.run("buggy_function(10)")

They mention that:

When you run the code, the debugger starts before executing buggy_function(10)
At the (Pdb) prompt, you need to use n to step into function buggy_function.

An example session output given the blog was as below:
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) n
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) s
> <string>(1)buggy_function()
(Pdb) p x
10
(Pdb) n
> <string>(3)buggy_function()
(Pdb) p i
4
(Pdb) p result
6.0
(Pdb) c
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

However, when I run the program (using > python ./main.py), I get the following output
(codeexec) PS C:\codeexec> python .\main.py
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) n
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) 

It seems like pressing n at this point, has caused the program to run the function and returned the exception.
If, however, I start with s, then the control steps into the method properly
(codeexec) PS C:\codeexec> python .\main.py
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> c:\codeexec\main.py(3)buggy_function()
-> def buggy_function(x):
(Pdb) n
> c:\codeexec\main.py(4)buggy_function()
-> result = 0
(Pdb) n
> c:\codeexec\main.py(5)buggy_function()
-> for i in range(x):
(Pdb) n
> c:\codeexec\main.py(6)buggy_function()
-> result += i / (i - 4)
(Pdb) p i
0
(Pdb) 

What I don't understand is why so many blogs are insisting to type n to debug the function, when we need to press s. Am I missing something here?

Can you give an example of one of these blogs? Are you sure they used pdb.run("buggy_function(10)"), rather than some other method of starting pdb, like putting pdb.set_trace() inside buggy_function?

The behaviour you see is correct. Typing n at the debug prompt runs the function, you need s to step into it. This is clearly stated in the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/pdb.html#module-pdb; which is always a better reference than other people's blogs.

I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be based on either a misunderstanding or on bad sources which are not specified.

Thanks everyone for your comments and I apologize for replying late. @OldBoy thanks for the documentation, I have read it now thoroughly and it has cleared my doubts. Lesson learnt, always follow documentation in case of any doubts.
